# How do you perform a package install as 'root' via sudo in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

With chef, is it possible to add something to a recipe that is installing a package to make the package command run as the super user rather than run the chef command as the super user, e.g.

```
package "mysql" do
  user: sudo
  action :install
end
```

So this would execute sudo apt-get install mysql rather than apt-get install mysql. Can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if you need root access to configure the system, you run the entire chef-client process under sudo, rather than as a normal user.

However, a member of the community created a ["chef-sudo" rubygem](http://rubygems.org/gems/chef-sudo) to assist with this.